# EC2 server always at 100% CPU

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a ubuntu precise server running on AWS EC2 micro with apache2 and Django.

The CPU usage has recently jumped to 100% gradually and I don't understand whether it's amazon cutting my usage or the actual computation done on it that have become heavier.

What could be the cause of such behavior and how can I improve performance of my web server?

**Edit: I am suspecting that some crontab jobs I am running are slowing the server down**

Comment: This type of question is probably not best for StackOverflow as it is discussion-prone and does not ask about any specific issue. Please feel free to edit the question to make the question more specific. You can refer to help (http://stackoverflow.com/help) section for guidance on how to ask SO appropriate questions.

Comment: this would be more of a question for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I will know for next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled the crontab jobs and CPU is now down at 40%.